# Get the selected option list in array to send

Tags: jquery, selected, optgroup

I need to get the selected values for filtering a table.
My selection code is as follows
    `<select id="myGroupFilter">

<optgroup label="Group0">
<option value="1">Value 1</option>

<option value="2">Value 2</option>

<option value="3">Value 3</option>

<option value="4">Value 4</option>

</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group1">

<option value="5">Value 5</option>

<option value="6">Value 6</option>

<option value="7">Value 7</option>

<option value="8">Value 8</option>

</optgroup>

</select>`

I tried this
`alert($("#myGroupFilter option:selected").text());`

But I am not getting any value. Please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: When do you need it? onclick, onsubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the below line to get the selected value

```
($("#myGroupFilter").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using jquery multiselect for this filter and it gave me another option

```
    $("#control_6").multiSelect( null, function(el) { el.val() });
```

el.val() gave me the required checkbox selected.

Thank you.